# Writing custom variable selection method using the CPLEX Python API

Tags: python, cplex

I want to implement a custom variable selection heuristic for solving an MLP using the CPLEX Python API.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any examples or documentation for this.

Ist this actually possible using the CPLEX Python API, or do I need to use C++?

Can I achieve this using the BranchCallback [1]?

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.callbacks.BranchCallback-class.html

Comment: wich Python API, what are you using?

Comment: CPLEX, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of the [BranchCallback](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.callbacks.BranchCallback-class.html) in the CPLEX Python API should be nearly identical to that of [BranchCallbackI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_BranchCallbackI.html) provided in the C++ API. Parallel callbacks are hindered by the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (aka, the GIL) in Python, however.

The `admipex1.py`, and `admipex3.py` Python examples demonstrate how to use the `BranchCallback` class and are included with CPLEX. For the corresponding C++ examples, see `iloadmipex1.cpp` and `iloadmipex3.cpp`.